# Saving arbitrary length mp3 stream

Tags: firefox, audio-recording

Using the <audio> control in FF, the context menu (right click) has a 'Save Audio As' selection that allows me to download the current mp3 stream directly to disc.

The problem I've encountered with internet-radio streams that don't actually have a file-size (they don't really 'end') is stopping the stream at an arbitrary point and saving the partial-audio clip.

The only way I'm currently able to stop downloading the stream (to disc) is to actually cancel the download, but this results in FF deleting what has been saved to disc up to that point.

Is there a way to stop the download and keep the mp3 data that has already been written to disc to save these partial-audio clips?

An example source would be any continuous mp3 shoutcast station: just save it to disc, no encoding necessary, no frame reconciliation required (it's already in a format I can use), no additional javascript needed.

Comment: Is this programming related? Do you absolutely have to use Firefox and not a more suitable tool?

Comment: I have a scheduler/player (javascript) that I want to add recording functionality to without additional calls into WebRTC or the like, as it seems rather pointless when a simple direct mp3 download is all that's necessary in this case. As for FF specificity, possibly not. I only mention FF as that's the platform I'm using for initial development.

Comment: @Matti: I've decided to move the project over to nw.js. You are absolutely right in that there are better avenues to achieve everything I'm attempting to do. If you want, leave an answer expressing this and I'll mark it as accepted to close-out this question.